# ExpertAdvisor within ExpertAdvisor .. nested EA

Tags: mql4, mt4

I have an MT4-EA but no code of it. The EA is working fine - but sensitive to news...

So, my idea would be to create a new EA that just watches news.
and reference the other EA inside the new one. when news get active i just want to disable the other EA and when its over to resume it.

is this somehow possible? or another idea?
can i referenve another ea to run within another including their input values?

tried not much yet...
im looking for ideas to solve this issue before creating tons of code...

ANSWER: ... found a solution
Its not possible to "control" another EA - but..
You open, close a chart by using a template.
other EA can be applied and chart saved as template.
the other EA can then just open/close the chart with template.

```
   long id = ChartOpen("EURUSD",PERIOD_H1);
   
   ChartApplyTemplate(id, "TemplateName.tpl");
```

Comment: Avoid questions that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last suggestion in [this thread](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/109115) maybe you could have one EA keeping an eye on a newsfeed and creating files with instructions that can be read by the second EA.

Plz keep us updated if any progression!